# ArgoCD with Bitnami Sealed Secrets

Tags: kubernetes, bitnami, argocd, cdk8s, sealedsecret

I am trying to install sealedsecrets as an app to argocd. I have all my sealedsecrets yaml files stored in eee_ops. But I am facing 2 problems
a) sync keeps failing in my argocd app as the resource version of the sealedsecret keeps changing with every sync giving this below error(pic1)
b) Some of my sealedsecrets health show up as degraded although everything seems alright(pic2)

Comment: Hi, You forgot the screenshots ;-)

Comment: Hi @abc123, Bitnami developer here, please add the images to the post so we can help you :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.